# pip list -o with target library without virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

1. Is there any existing functionality to show outdated packages that are contained within a target lib directory installed with the equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib` without the use of a virtualenv? Maybe some working form of `pip list -o -t lib`
2. If no functionality or simple workaround exists, what would be the proper way of maintaining packages in an external target library?

Comment: Why are you not using a virtualenv? One approach could be having a virtualenv, and synching packages from it elsewhere.

Comment: @9000 It's an issue more of convenience, but one reason is to allow a separation of concerns between a development environment and production environment where only some of the packages in the development virtualenv are actually needed.

Comment: For that purpose, I usually keep 2 (or even 3) requirements files: one for prod (manually maintained), one with dev conveniences, and another with test-only dependencies (needed by CI). The two latter have  `-r requirements-prod.txt` to include the prod requirements.

Comment: @9000 Thanks for that thought. The way my prod-environment is set up, I would still need a separate lib directory that needs to be deployed (can't simply deploy a requirements-prod.txt file and have requirements install during deployment), so finding a simple way to independently maintain an separate lib or site-packages directory is still the primary concern. Unless you meant you also maintain multiple virtual environments for a single project?

Comment: I can imagine a build step that creates a (new, empty) virtualenv, installs packages into it, and copies them from virtualenv's dir to target dir. This does look a bit convoluted. OTOH I don't see _any_ Python deployment outside of a virtualenv, or an otherwise isolated environment, as a reasonable thing to do. If my target OS has a system Python installed, I only consider managing it via the OS's package manager, never via `pip`.